# How to display alternative object's representation inside ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Some time ago I have encountered post in which the author stated that if I have a `ListBox` the objects inside of it do not have to be represented by `string` returned by `ToString()` method inside of the `ListBox`

How is it possible?

For instance I have a:

```
 public class Car {
        public static int ID { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public int Power { get; set; }


        public Car(string Make, int Power) {
            Id = ID++;
            this.Make = Make;
            this.Power = Power;
            AddToClassExtension(this);
        }


        public override string ToString() {
            return Id + "." + Make + " " + Power;
        }
}
```

and a `ListBox lb` in a `Form`. I want to display only `car.Id` in every row of the `lb` but do not change `ToString()` method. Is it possible?

Comment: Aside from anything else, why do you have a static `ID` property and an instance `Id` property? That seems like a recipe for confusion. (At least make it private and give it a different name, such as `IdCounter`.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I wanted to implement autonumeration. So I created static field with value 0 and I have corresponding object field `Id`. How should I call the static field here?

Comment: I've just edited my comment - I'd make it private, and name it with some indication that it's not an ID, it's a counter. Also note that it's not thread-safe at the moment, which isn't ideal. If you make it private, you can just have it as a static field (not a property) and use `Interlocked.Increment`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember) for the `ListBox` - in this case you'd set it to `"Id"` so that the control would fetch that property from each item being displayed.

Here's a short but complete example (using C# 6 for brevity):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Car {
    // C# 6 finally allows read-only autoprops. Yay!
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Make { get; set; }

    public Car(int id, string make)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Make = make;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Id + "." + Make;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var cars = new List<Car>
        {
            new Car(10, "Ford"),
            new Car(20, "Nissan"),
            new Car(45, "Rolls-Royce")
        };

        var listBox = new ListBox
        {
            DataSource = cars,
            DisplayMember = "Id",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        };

        var form = new Form
        { 
            Controls = { listBox }
        };
        Application.Run(form);
    }
}
```

For more complex formatting, you can use the `Format` event, after enabling formatting. For example, in the above example, change the `listBox` declaration to:

```
var listBox = new ListBox
{
    DataSource = cars,
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    FormattingEnabled = true,
};
listBox.Format += (sender, args) =>
{
    var car = (Car) args.Value;
    args.Value = string.Format("Id: {0}; Make: {1}", car.Id, car.Make);
};
```

Comment: What If I would like to get  two fields out of the instance of `Car` I tried:   `carListBox.DisplayMember = "Id,Make";`. The `carListBox.DisplayMember = "Id" worked fine thaugh.

Comment: @Yoda: I don't think that's feasible just using `DisplayMember`. I think you could use `FormatString` in conjunction with a custom format provider, but that would start getting tricky.

Comment: @Yoda: I've just worked out a way to do it; I'll add that at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: That worked great but I don't really know what is `args.Value` here. Beause once it is a `Car` and then you assign a `string` to it. I see that whatever is assigned to the `args.Value` is displayed in the `ListBox` but I don't understand the mechanism behind it.

Comment: @Yoda: Did you read the documentation for the `Format` event and the `ListControlConvertEventArgs` class it uses?

Comment: Pure gold found...